# Action not being called when button is tapped in a stack view

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistackview

I have a custom view that includes a stack view. Inside the stack view I have a label and a button.

I created my stack view, label and button in the following way and added them to the parent view.

```
class HomeView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(haveAccount)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(signin)
    stackView.setCustomSpacing(4.0, after: haveAccount)
}

let stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView()
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stack.alignment = .fill
    stack.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return stack
}()

let haveAccount: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    ...
    return label
}()

let signin: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Sign in", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeController.loginClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

}
```

In my view controller I add the view to the controller's base view and set the constraints. I also create the method that should be called when the signin button is tapped.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeView = HomeView()
    homeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(homeView)
    homeView.fullscreenView(parentView: view)
}

@objc func loginClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    print("sign in button pressed")
}
```

When I press the button the loginClicked method is not called. Now I did tried moving the loginClicked method to the custom view and changing the addTarget accordingly and loginClicked method is called. This being said I know the button is clickable but I don't think the target for the button action is correct and that is why the loginClicked method in the view controller is not being called.

Comment: Did you try to remove the line `stack.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`? or change it to `true`

Comment: Yep, tried this and get same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Protocol/Delegation

```
//1. Create a protocol

protocol HomeViewDelegate{
    func loginButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)
}

class HomeView: UIView {

    //2. Create a delegate
    var delegate: HomeViewDelegate?

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return stack
    }()

    let haveAccount: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        return label
    }()

    let signin: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Sign in", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(haveAccount)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(signin)
        stackView.setCustomSpacing(4.0, after: haveAccount)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

   //3. Call your protocol method via delegate
   @objc func loginClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if let delegate = delegate{
            delegate.loginButtonClicked(sender: sender)
        }
    }

}
```

In You Caller ViewController create an extension

```
extension ViewController: HomeViewDelegate{
    func loginButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        print("login Button Clicked")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you set `userInteractionEnabled` property of your stackView to false, set it to true. Then if it does not work consider the following approach:

There are two possible ways to fix this, first is adding the target from ViewController, and the other one is using delegation.

I think the first way would be easier to implement for you.

You need to add your target from your `ViewController` class.

First update your view class and get rid of adding a target:

```
class HomeView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
  super.init(frame: frame)
  translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  addSubview(stackView)
  stackView.addArrangedSubview(haveAccount)
  stackView.addArrangedSubview(signin)
  stackView.setCustomSpacing(4.0, after: haveAccount)
}

let stackView: UIStackView = {
  let stack = UIStackView()
  stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
  stack.alignment = .fill
  stack.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  return stack
}()

let haveAccount: UILabel = {
  let label = UILabel()
  ...
  return label
}()

let signin: UIButton = {
  let button = UIButton()
  button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  button.setTitle("Sign in", for: .normal)
  button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14)
  button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
  return button
}()

}
```

Now in your `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    homeView = HomeView()
    homeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    homeView.signIn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(homeView)
    homeView.fullscreenView(parentView: view)
}

@objc func loginClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    print("sign in button pressed")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the target in the button definition and moved it to the view controller like above but I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @user2569905 did you set `isUserInteractionEnabled` of `stackView` to true?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the **right constraints**, I had this problem, I had this problem and the solution was this.

**Solution:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol HomeViewDelegate:class{
    func loginButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)
}

class HomeView: UIView {

    //2. Create a delegate
    weak var delegate: HomeViewDelegate?

    var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return stack
    }()

    let haveAccount: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = .gray
        label.text = "Label"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    let signin: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Sign in", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(haveAccount)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(signin)
        stackView.setCustomSpacing(4.0, after: haveAccount)

        addSubview(stackView)
       
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                
            self.stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            self.stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            self.stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            self.stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)

        ])

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

   //3. Call your protocol method via delegate
   @objc func loginClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if let delegate = delegate{
            delegate.loginButtonClicked(sender: sender)
        }
    }

}
```

**ViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let homeView = HomeView()

    homeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    homeView.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(homeView)
        
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            homeView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            homeView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            homeView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            homeView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)

     ])
}

@objc func loginClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    print("sign in button pressed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your button code

```
button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

re-active **isUserInteractionEnabled** ***again***

```
let signin: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        button.setTitle("Sign in", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.loginClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        return button
    }()
```